# Как сделать, чтобы часть layout выходила за границы экрана?

Tags: android, android-layout

Добрый день! Не могу найти ответ на вопрос. Есть layout с картинкой (или использовать ImageView). Необходимо чтобы в начале часть его была за экраном устройства, а при нажатии кнопки например, выплывала полностью на экран.
Как ни размещаю - ограничивает экраном его и масштабирует. Может есть какой-то флаг или атрибут? Пробовал и отступать и жестко задавать большие значения ширины и высоты слоя/вью.

Comment: `imageView.setY(-100);`

Comment: Спасибо! Долго не мог понять как.

Comment: Я написал это в ответ - вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от его тела)

Comment: [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете сделать это, задав абсолютное значение координаты для View методом `setY(float y)` передав отрицательное значение в качестве аргумента:

```
imageView.setY(-100);
```

Comment: кстати, а не подскажите, как сделать чтобы картинка заезжала и вправо и влево?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, чтоб влево уехала надо аналогично `setX(-100)` вызвать. Чтоб при этом вправо уехала, надо чтоб ширина была больше ширины экрана.

Comment: спасибо, попробую)